# Restricting public access to entire WP website

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I plan on having my website undergo scheduled maintenance, and simply want to restrict any access to the site or its subpages **unless its coming from my IP**. I would like to **redirect anyone else** to a temporary page instead.

I've seen the modifying the htaccess like:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 98.6.000.111
```

But **1)** this doesn't allow me to *temporarily* redirect users to another HTML page and **2)** speaking of *temporarily*, in my experience users have had their browsers cache the htaccess and even after I change it, they were still being redirected and this is obviously undesirable.

Are there any other strategies, or ways to prevent the issues mentioned above with the htaccess method?

**Note: I am not using a plugin for this as the site is undergoing massive changes including swapping of plugins/code/etc so I need the redirect to be more higher-level than WP-level stuff.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a 302 temporary redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^98.6.000.111
RewriteRule .* http://www.anothersite.com [R=302,L]
```

or (you almost got it right)

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.anothersite.com
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 98.6.000.111
```

The last option has some caveats depending on your WordPress folder structure.

In the case of redirecting to subdomain you can do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^98.6.000.111
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yourdomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/yoursubdirectory/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /yoursubdirectory/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yourdomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ yoursubdirectory/index.html [R=302,L]
```

Explanation:

- The 1st line enables Apache’s rewrite engine, mod_rewrite.
- The 2nd line checks if the request is coming from your IP. If it is, then the redirect does not happen.
- The 3rd line takes makes sure requests to http/https and www/non-www are used.
- The 4th line prevents an infinite-loop scenario by testing the request against the name of your subdirectory.
- The last line basically redirects all requests that meet all previous rewrite conditions to the specified subdirectory and file.

Comment: Thanks. Would this work if I want to prevent users from accessing mysite.com, mysite.com/post-title/, mysite.com/activity/members/profile, etc **BUT** allow me to redirect them to mysite.com/temporary-brb-page ? (I feel like the htaccess would do an endless loop or something?)